# Long Tail Phenomenon For Kafka Event Consumption

Tags: apache-kafka

Our production encounter one Kafka Event Consumption phenomenon.
Total event Volume is 3.4 Billion Events with 40 partitions. And event message almost even distribute on each partition with 80+ million event per partition.

And we allocate 40 consumer streams with 40 threads (BTW, we 're using kafka client 0.8.2).

During Consumption periods, on the **first 4** hours each partition's lag keep drop down. On the **last one** hour, 2/3 consumer streams have finished event consumption. Only less than 10 consumer stream continue to receive remaining events.
For the related less than 10 partition's lag ranges on 2-3 millions.
It means consumer pool usage gradually back to idle while waiting for remaining few consumer finish tasks.

Assume cpu cores & memory space & network bandwidth is enough, any tips to ensure Kafka consumer can finish overall consumption within one time and no more consumer fall behind (Except for enlarge partition number).

Comment: Did you have a look at what queuing theory says for your case. Is the long tail to be expected or do you have a statistical artifact in your partitioning?

Comment: Long tail is not what we expected. Ideally, we want to each consumer stream finish in one time or within minor time gap between.

Comment: What I mean with 'expecting' is: given your partition distribution is uniform and your compute time per message has a certain distribution, Normal or Poisson or something, then it may be the case that the long tail is exactly what must happen with high probability.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real cool one. I suspect there is no Kafka solution, except the one you mention (increase # partitions).

Hmm, a totally silly idea could be as follows: during end-game, switch to copying into a new topic with *less* partitions, e.g. 37 (relatively prime to 40) in the hope to reshuffle all messages such that they are again evenly distributed over the 37 partitions. Of course this assumes a lot: a) copying is faster than processing, b) there is really no way to increase your initial 40 partitions, c) you've got the space and resources for the additional topic.